# Will Outlook out-of-office reply go to mailing lists?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, mailing-lists, out-of-office, auto-reply

I subscribe to mailing lists, and have rules that route them to folders under my inbox.

Will setting up an out-of-office auto-reply send a message to the public list for every incoming message?

Comment: If you want to know for sure, just try it using a separate accound and public list.

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about the kind of mailing lists where you send a mail to a a mailing list server and the software resends the mail to all recipients:

RFC 3834 defines a mail header line that tells your mail server (Exchange) that it should *not* send an out-of-office mail. The mailing list server should add it to mails that it resends:

```
Auto-submitted: auto-generated
```

This header line is defined in RFC 3834. Just check whether this line is in the mails that you get from the mailing list.

RFC 3834 obsoletes another, older, non-standard, widely used header line:

```
Precedence: bulk
```

Microsoft Exchange Server knows about an additional, non-standard header line:

```
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: 00F
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219609(v=exchg.80).aspx for documentation.

A fourth way to handle the problem is to use an empty bounce address. In order to do this, use the following header line:

```
Sender: <>
```

Sometimes, author and sender are not the same (remailers?). `From` should be the author. `Sender` is the contact address of the sender and thereby the one that you should contact in case of delivery issues (i.e. vacation etc.) (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4367471/601203). `<>` seems to be some kind of null value for mail addresses.

Setting the `Sender` seems to work quite reliably.

One more thing: Many mail server know they should not reply to mailing lists (?). Thus, if a mailing list uses the proper header, that's sufficient for avoiding vacation mails:

```
List-Id: Knitting Mailing List <knitting.example.com>
```

Comment: Do you have any evidence that Exchange honors this header? All I can find says that it only honors the older `Precedence:` and its private `X-Auto-Response-Suppress:`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff848256%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx, Exchange 2010 conforms to RFC 3834.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. Automatic Replies (Out of Office) are sent to the sender of the incoming email and regardless the source of incoming email.

To avoid it, you need to setup a rule to exclude those addresses.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid haveing an out of office response sent to outside of your organization senders, when setting the OOO Open the tab tilted "Outside My Oranization", make sure the "Auto-reply to people outside my organization is not checked.  An additional option on this tab is to have responses sent to "My contacts only"

Answer (score 0):

Correction to the otherwise excellent answer by @hagello:

The values for `X-Auto-Response-Suppress` should be the capital letter O, not the number 0.  OOF is an abbreviation for Out Of Office.

```
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: OOF
```

See [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2006/10/06/exchange-server-2007-out-of-office-oof/).